# How to configure different levels for different appenders but under same logger in logback

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, logging, logback

We are writing 2 appenders to write logs in different formats to 2 different files.
But we want to enable these logs based on some configuration.

So if the user wants to enable both of the formats, then both of logs will be printed. But if the user wants to disable one, that log should not be created.

Below is my logger configuration :

```
<logger name="package.name" additivity="false" level="DEBUG">
     <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
     <appender-ref ref="json_logs"/>
     <appender-ref ref="text_logs"/>
</logger>
```

Now I want to put separate levels for this appender-ref. and value of these levels either should come from some property file which will be edited by user or user could simply update **logback.xml** file only.

I am not able to find a way to put separate levels for these appenders.
And since I have to write logs from same classes, I cant create 2 separate loggers too.

Also, if the user does not want to see txt logs, then the corresponding log.txt file should not be created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after is the ThresholdFilter which can be fine tuned for each appender:

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html#thresholdFilter

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- deny all events with a level below INFO, that is TRACE and DEBUG -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    ...
</appender>
```

As for not writing the file at all based on some flag... you could write your own appender. Something like this ultra-simplistic example that could be refined in a number of ways but should hopefully get you started:

```
public class ConditionalAppender<E> extends OutputStreamAppender<E> {

    private boolean masterSwitch;

    private String file;

    @Override
    public void start() {

        if(masterSwitch)
            setOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
        else 
            setOutputStream(new NullOutputStream());

        super.start();
    }

    public void setMasterSwitch(final boolean enabled) {

        this.masterSwitch = enabled;
    }

    public void setFile(final String file) {

        this.file = file;
    }
}

<appender name="CONDITIONAL" class="mypackage.ConditionalAppender">
    <!-- switch this appender on or off -->
    <masterSwitch>true</masterSwitch>
    <!-- set the output file -->
    <file>/var/log/app/app.log</file>
    <!-- deny all events with a level below INFO, that is TRACE and DEBUG -->
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>INFO</level>
    </filter>
    ...
</appender>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but using this filter still creates the log file. It just does not write to log file. is there any way to disable logs entirely.

Comment: I'll have to think about that one. I'll update my post shortly.

Comment: Hi @Captain creating appender class has few concerns. I would have to take  my logic for rolling files, choosing file name at java class which some what taking away symmetry from my logback.xml as there are other properties too which I am using in logback.xml. Is there any way you can suggest at logback.xml or even with custom appender is fine but then I would have to declare file name also out of logback.xml

Comment: @Onki I have amended my example to show how properties could be injected using JavaBeans introspection. I think I have answered your question in that my solution can be configured in the XML to not output the file at all and control the logging level at the appender. How about an upvote?

Comment: As for rolling files, that's a bit of question creep there and honestly, it's a big one. It could be done by extending RollingFileAppender rather than OutputStreamAppender and I think my example shows enough to get you started. Anything more than that this and I will have to discuss consulting rates first :). The limiting factor is your requirement to not output the file at all if the appender is disabled, that is simply not something the existing appenders will do out of the box.

Comment: @Onki I put quite some time and effort into this and would like to see you through. Was my help sufficient to get you unstuck?

Comment: yes @captain, your answer gave me information over the topic asked. But for my project we changed this appraoch.We chose to activate appenders based on user profile selected in spring boot project.